# how to call from a objective c class to view controller class in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am calling method from view controller class to objective c 'dbhelper' class and vice versa. when i call method of dbhelper class  from view controller class. like this  i have created a method for button in view controller and within this method i am calling to dbhelper class like this

```
- (IBAction) clickme 
{
dbhelper *dbhelp = [[dbhelper alloc] init];
[dbhelp dbhelperclassmethod];
}
```

its working fine but when i call method of view controller class from dbhelper class then method calling not work like this i had created method in dbhelper class from there i am calling to viewcontroller class method like this

```
  -(void) disableview
    {
       ViewController *Controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        [Controller ViewControllerclassmethod];

  }
```

so this method not calling the viewcontroller class method, the above code is not the orignal code but i write this code for ur understanding so that you give answer to me what is the problem .so kindly tell me why i am not able to call viewcontroller class from dbhelper class thanks

Comment: First question I'd have is whether or not Controller is nil. You may just not be initing it correctly.

Comment: How do you know that `ViewControllerclassmethod` is not being called?  Did you try stepping into it in the debugger or using NSLog() to print a message?

Comment: Also, those are Instance Methods. Well, at least they should be considering you're sending the messages to instances and not class objects.

Comment: A view controller IS an Objective-C class, so there's no difference calling VC from "Objective-C class" than there is calling from one class to the next.

Comment: Don't use a name with an initial upper-case character for a variable name or a method name.  Don't use a name with an initial lower-case character for a class name.

Answer (score 2):

That looks to me like you are creating a new instance of `ViewController` in your `dbhelper` class, and sending the `ViewControllerclassmethod` to that new instance, instead of to the instance you expect. If you want to have your instance of `dbhelper` call the method in the instance of `ViewController` from which you call `dbhelper`, then you have to tell `dbhelper` where to send the message. Something like:

```
dbhelp.callingViewController = self;
```

in your instance of ViewController. Then `dbhelper` can do

```
[self.callingViewController ViewControllerclassmethod];
```

Of course, in `dbhelper.h`, there has to be a

```
@property (strong) ViewController * callingViewController;
```

The `Controller` you are referring to in your `disableview` method above is an entirely new ViewController, completely separate from the original one that called `dbhelper`.

Another hint: the conventions about naming in objective C are actually very useful. The class you call `dbhelper` would be better called `DatabaseHelper` (upper-case 'D') and the local variable `Controller` would be better called `controller`. Others, and soon you, will find it easier to follow your code. Similarly, `disableView` and `viewControllerInstanceMethod` (and not class method, which is quite a different thing).

Comment: That should be "viewControllerInstanceMethod".

Comment: I missed that! Thanks very much for pointing it out, I edited the answer.